# Парсить только цифру из нужного блока

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть сайт с разметкой:

```
<a href="/user/search.php"><div class="nav2"><img style="width:24px; height=24px" src="/style/icons/10.png" alt="*">
поиск людей </div></a>
<a href="/new_face.php"><div class="nav2"><img src="/style/icons/user_female_white_rb.png" alt="*" height="24" width="24"> Новые лица </div></a>
<a href="/new_mess.php"><div class="nav2"><img src="/style/icons/users_go.png" alt="*" height="28" width="28"> Сообщения <font color="red">2</font></div></a>
```

Мне с этой разметки нужно парсить только цифру, которая находится в блоке `nav2` и выделена `<font color="red">2</font>`. В этом блоке есть еще текст `Сообщиния` - этот тект парсить не нужно.

Собственно вопрос, как это сделать? Учитывая то что этот блок третий по счету и то что нужно выбрать только цифру.

Для парсинга использую **jsoup** . Пытался так:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Document doc = null;
            try {

                doc = Jsoup
                      .connect("http://mobayle.ru")
                      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                      .referrer("http://google.com").timeout(1000 * 5)
                      .ignoreContentType(true).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Elements popTovAll = doc.select("div.nav2");

                my_number = popTovAll.text();
                func();



        }
    }).start();
```

но в так получается что парсит самый последний блок `nav2` и парсит все что в нем находится.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как в метод `select` передаётся CSS-selector, вы можете уточнить его:

```
Elements popTovAll = doc.select("div.nav2 font[color=red]");
```

Это означает «найти тег font с атрибутом color=red внутри тега div с классом nav2». Что как будто бы подходит под вашу разметку.

Или даже так:

```
Elements popTovAll = doc.select("a[href*=new_mess] div.nav2 font[color=red]");
```

Что означает «найти тег font с атрибутом color=red внутри тега div с классом nav2 внутри тега a, у которого href содержит new_mess»

Если найденных элементов много и вам надо достать один элемент по порядковому номеру из найденных, это тоже можно легко сделать:

```
Element popTov = popTovAll.get(0);
String num = popTov.text();
```

Comment: а если на сайте еще есть теги **font** внутри блока `nav2` - что тогда? поэтому я и хочу выбрать именно третий блок

Comment: @Денис, селекторы — мощная штука, их можно уточнять сколько угодно. Я поменял ответ, чтобы искало только конкретно с `color=red`. Если этого недостаточно, приведите более полную разметку, чтобы было понятно, как отличить конкретно этот элемент от других. Наконец, если селектор нашёл много элементов, никто не мешает из полученного объекта `Elements` достать конкретный по порядковому номеру (`popTovAll.get(3)`, например).

Comment: но дело в том что в теге font значение `color=red` везде.

Comment: Ну можно на ссылку в окружающем `a` заложиться, например (ещё отредактировал).

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за развернутый ответ!